# Why are the bob databases (e.g. bob.db.arface) not available for Python 3.8

Tags: python-bob

I have lately installed the latest version of Bob (particularly, the package bob.bio.face) (9.0) using conda and following the installation instructions. This automatically installed python version 3.8. When I try to run

```
bob bio pipelines vanilla-biometrics arface gabor_graph
```

I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bob.db.arface'`

So, I try to install bob.db.arface: `conda install bob.db.arface`. For some reason, this wants to install a whole new python version (3.7), and reinstall all bob packages.

Looking at the pipelines of `bob.db.arface` (https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.db.arface/pipelines/45435), I can see that only python 3.6 and 3.7 is supported. It seems to be that this is true for many of the `bob.db` packages. Will there be versions for python 3.8 available, or do I need to downgrade to python 3.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new release of bob we deprecated all database packages and porting them one by one (once we have the time for it) to the new database interface (https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.bio.face/-/issues/54).
If you want to use the old `bob.dbs` and the legacy database support (https://www.idiap.ch/software/bob/docs/bob/bob.bio.base/stable/legacy.html), please, rely on bob for `py37`.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You may pip install the bob.db.arface package or use buildout but know that most bob.db. packages are deprecated in favor of the csv format. https://groups.google.com/g/bob-devel/c/6-4SxluHHrA